# How to check both conditions Laravel where clause

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

How to check both  conditions in following query,

```
->where('asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec', '=', 'call_r.duration')
->where('asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec', '>=', 45)
```

I need something like this

```
  ->where('asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec', '=', 'call_r.duration' and 'asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec', '>=', 45)
```

Comment: Im new to laravel. please any suggestion

Comment: The above two `where` will return same criteria as you asked for third `where` what is the real issue ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid when I remove one of where clause query works fine with that data. but both return 0 results.

Comment: types of columns -asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec - int, call_r.duration- big int

Comment: @ChandimalHarischandra have you checked that `call_r.duration` contains any value bigger or equal to 45? If  `call_r.duration` values are smaller than 45 the query will result will be empty

Comment: yes I have data

Comment: @ChandimalHarischandra does any `call_r.duration` value is >= 45?

Comment: @claudio yes many

Comment: @ChandimalHarischandra If you run that query directly on the database does it work?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions), try:

```
->whereRaw('asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec = call_r.duration AND asteriskcdrdb.cdr.billsec >= 45');
```